# Order of execution of instance variables

Tags: java

I know about static and intialization block in a class and their order of execution. But the following code causes some doubts.

```
class Test1 {
   Test1(int x) {
      System.out.println("Constructor value : " + x);
   }
}

public class Test2 {
   Test1 t1 = new Test1(10);    ----- line 8
   Test2(int i) {
       t1 = new Test1(i);
   } 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Test2 t2 = new Test2(5);
  }
}
```

This code's output :
 
**Constructor value : 10 

 Constructor value : 5**

My question is that the instance variable (line 8) is executed as soon as the object for the class(Test2) is created or some other stuff happens.

Comment: why don't you answer your own question by placing System.out.println() at each line and constructor?

Comment: Your best bet here is to step through the code a statement at a time using the debugger built into your IDE.

Comment: By the way, you don't have any static initializers in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initializers and initialization blocks are executed as though they were inserted into every constructor right at the top (in a base class) or just after the call to `super(...)` (in a subclass).¹ So your `Test2` is functionally identical to:

```
public class Test2 {
   Test1 t1;
   Test2(int i) {
       t1 = new Test1(10);
       t1 = new Test1(i);
   } 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Test2 t2 = new Test2(5);
  }
}
```

---

¹ In fact, that's *literally* true if you look at the bytecode...

For instance, suppose we add a second constructor to `Test2`:

```
public class Test2 {
    Test1 t1 = new Test1(10);

    Test2(int i) {
        t1 = new Test1(i);
    } 

    Test2(int i, String s) {
        t1 = new Test1(i);
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 t2 = new Test2(5);
    }
}
```

then compile it, and use `javap -c Test2` to see the bytecode (roughly):

```
Compiled from "Test2.java"
public class Test2 {
  Test1 t1;

  Test2(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: new           #2                  // class Test1
       8: dup
       9: bipush        10
      11: invokespecial #3                  // Method Test1."<init>":(I)V
      14: putfield      #4                  // Field t1:LTest1;
      17: aload_0
      18: new           #2                  // class Test1
      21: dup
      22: iload_1
      23: invokespecial #3                  // Method Test1."<init>":(I)V
      26: putfield      #4                  // Field t1:LTest1;
      29: return

  Test2(int, java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: new           #2                  // class Test1
       8: dup
       9: bipush        10
      11: invokespecial #3                  // Method Test1."<init>":(I)V
      14: putfield      #4                  // Field t1:LTest1;
      17: aload_0
      18: new           #2                  // class Test1
      21: dup
      22: iload_1
      23: invokespecial #3                  // Method Test1."<init>":(I)V
      26: putfield      #4                  // Field t1:LTest1;
      29: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #5                  // class Test2
       3: dup
       4: iconst_5
       5: invokespecial #6                  // Method "<init>":(I)V
       8: astore_1
       9: return
}
```

You can see the `t1 = new Test1(10)` in both constructors.

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere - Sure! Compile a class, then use `javap -c ClassName` to see a slightly-annotated copy of the bytecode. :-D

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere - ...but I couldn't resist adding it. ;-)